# Swift 'thread 1 signal sigabrt' Error

Tags: swift, tableview

I am trying to implement a tableview with different sections. Before putting this code in, the app ran fine. I understand this error pops up from outlets that are not connected properly, so I believe the error is coming from the IBOutlet I set with my TableView. But I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Below is my code:

```
import UIKit

class MainPageVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {


@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self

}
let textCellIdentifier = "cell"

let items = ["My Items", "Needed Items", "Future Items"]

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return items[section]
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return items.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: textCellIdentifier, for: indexPath)


    return cell
}



override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Well If you know that you outlets are not correct then make them correct. You can delete the IBOutlets and re-create them

Comment: Does not solve my issue. I am looking to see if I had set up my table view correctly, or if there is something else that I am missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not put in a prototype cell in the tableview, this got rid of the error.